# How to write an UPDATE statement when we need to check a condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I want to write an update statement in Oracle SQL to set True to a few properties only when another property in the same table is true.

```
    name   |    value
----------------------
property1       False
property2       False
property3       True
```

```
UPDATE table_xyz 
   SET value = 'True' 
WHERE name in ('property1', 'property2')
```

only when property3 = 'True';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like following using `EXISTS`.

```
UPDATE table_xyz 
   SET value = 'True' 
WHERE name in ('property1', 'property2') 
AND EXISTS
(
 SELECT 1 FROM table_xyz WHERE name = 'property3' AND value = 'True'
)
```

Comment: The inner query was corrected to :
```SELECT 1 FROM table_xyz WHERE name = 'property3' AND value = 'True'```

Answer (score 2):

As you said - *add* that condition:

```
UPDATE table_xyz a
   SET a.value = 'True' 
WHERE a.name in ('property1', 'property2') 
  AND 'True' = (SELECT b.value 
                FROM table_xyz b
                WHERE b.name = 'property3'
               )
```

(presuming that there's only one row whose name is `property3`; otherwise, you'll get `TOO_MANY_ROWS` error).